# MainActivity not running

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Help! I'm really new to Android Studio and not very good at it so please be as simple as possible when explaining things to me. Soo on the MainActivty for this app, its supposed to be where the user can enter data and then click a button and the data is displayed in the result activity using shared preferences... the rest of my app runs but when I tried running the mainactivity, it just closed out my avd. I'll include my code. can anyone see a reason why it wouldnt run?

```
package edu.wmich.games;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String strName;
    String strEmail;
    int intGames;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        final EditText games = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnumber);
        Button btngamer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngames);


        final SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        btngamer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

                strName = name.getText().toString();
        strEmail = email.getText().toString();
        intGames = Integer.parseInt(games.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();

        editor.putString("keyName", strName);
        editor.putString("keyEmail", strEmail);
        editor.putInt("keyGames", intGames);

        editor.commit();

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class));


        }
    }
```

Comment: It would provably be a good idea to actually paste the code here instead of a screenshot. LogCat would also be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the logs.

Comment: The rest of your app runs? How can be that, this is your MainActivity and it´s not working =)

Comment: what error are you getting??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `View.onClickListener` after `AppCompatActivity`.
You might have to import something after you do this but `View.onClickListener` needs to be written at the top of the activity so your app knows to be listening

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the final datatype of the EditText view, A final variable can only be initialized once, so after execution you cant modify the variable, change the data type to String, and try.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the `MainActivity` automatically makes an `intent` to open the Activity "Result"...

```
 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class));
```

I will think in two possible causes:

1)  Your `Activity` "Result" probably is not declared into your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
or

2) Your activity Result has an error that closes the application.